# Scrollable Video cropview with video Frames

Tags: android

I am creating Video Editing App.In This app i want to make functions like merge two or more videos.after merge video replace audio,add stickers at specific duration of video etc.I successfully added audio to video.now I work on add sticker to video.To add sticker or subtitle to video i need to display all frames of video to bottom and i Want to make video Rangebar that can select  video range and add subtitle to video.to implement this feature i checked many projects from github like following:

https://github.com/iknow4/Android-Video-Trimmer

https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer

https://github.com/deepandroid/video-trimmer

https://github.com/feigxj/Android-Video-Trimmer-master

and many more but these all project have only fix trim view not scallable.that can be scall on bitmaplist scrolling.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knowledge4life/k4l-video-trimmer/master/screenshot/screenshot.png

I want to create trimerview for stiker like following.

[image]

thanks.